# How to compare data in Netezza using DataStage

Tags: netezza, datastage

Can I compare these two rows using DataStage then update if the Status field changing?

```
    ID | desc | ... | ... | Status | Start_Date | End_Date
------------------------------------------------------------
123456 | ...  | ... | ... |   Y    | 12/31/2014 | 21/31/9999
123456 | ...  | ... | ... |   N    | 12/31/2014 | current_date
```

At beginning I only have this row

```
    ID | desc | ... | ... | Status | Start_Date | End_Date
------------------------------------------------------------
123456 | ...  | ... | ... |   Y    | 12/31/2014 | 21/31/9999
```

Then... I want to compare with this row

```
   ID | desc | ... | ... | Status | Start_Date | End_Date
------------------------------------------------------------
123456| ...  | ... | ... |   N    | 12/31/2014 | current_date
```

If the Status field changing from `Y` to `N`, I want to update the `End_Date` with `current_date`. If the Status field changing from `N` to `Y`, I want to update the `Start_Date` with `current_date` and `End_Date` with `12/31/9999` again. Is it possible to do this in DataStage?
I tried using Switch Processing, but stuck when I want to Update in Netezza Connector.

Answer (score 1):

From table only extract records which are having `End_Date` = `12/31/9999`

Then with look up stage compare on `ID` and Status with the new records, if match then sotre in to a update file and the one which do not match you can directly insert in to table.

And in the update file you must keep the both new records and the data which you fetch from table.

Now sort the records on `ID` and `Start_Date` in a transformer satge , and in a stage variable have if else condition  like if `Status` is N then end the date of previous date and populate `End_Date` = `12/31/9999` of current date.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Abhis for answering my question. It's about storing slow moving dimension using datastage. I tried to use SCD process but still failed. I miss with the Surrogate key, Business key, Type1, Type2, etc...